# the OIC warns that "cannot start spying, make sure the UFT developer runtime engine is up"

Tags: eclipse, hp-uft

I have installed the UFT developer engine on eclipse. now I start the runtime engine from the dropdown menu list on eclipse, then when I start OIC, it warns as what the title describes.

The version of the UFT developer is 2021 R1. My license is for the 30-day trial, and I am sure it is not expired.

could you please give me any solution to fix it?

Comment: interesting that it looks like even though I have a 30-day free trial, when I launch the eclipse with the runtime engine auto startup, I am asked for a valid license -- but if I only try starting this runtime engine, no alert will pop up.  I believe this explains everything -- I am never granted access to run runtime engine with a free trial.

Comment: and I reviewed the email 'Micro Focus Software Activation Information' again and it announced 'This evaluation product does not require a generated license key. The product software has a built-in evaluation period.'. So WTF?!

Comment: What is OIC? What is UFT? None of this is Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 UFT is a testing tool which creates an addon to eclipse, thus the eclipse tag is relevant.